# Relative Difference between two non-negative scalars

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation

I've been looking for a way to compare two values, and every idea I think of falls short in some way. Essentially, I want a function $f$ that meets these conditions for non-negative scalars $x, y$:

If $x = 1000$ and $y = 1100$, $f(x,y)$ is not significantly large.
If $x = 0$ and $y = 1$, $f(x,y)$ is not significantly large.
If $x = 100$ and $y = 300$, $f(x,y)$ is significantly large.
If $x = 0$ and $y = 100$, $f(x,y)$ is significantly large.

Possible options I've considered:

1. $f(x,y) = x-y$
2. $f(x,y) = \frac{x-y}{min(x,y)}$
3. $f(x,y) = \frac{x-y}{(x+y)/2}$
4. $f(x,y) = \frac{x-y}{max(min(x,y),1)}$

Problems with each option:

1. $f(6000,6100)$ = $f(100,0)$
2. Division by zero
3. $f(1,0) = f(100,0)$
4. This is the best option I've considered, and is often how K/D ratios are calculated in video games. Still, it feels odd and I believe that there exists a better solution.

Some other properties of my mythical function $f$:

$f(x,y) = -f(y,x)$
$f(x,x) = 0$

I realize I have not been precise with the values I want $f$ to return, but $f(x,y)$ should essentially be the answer to the question "how big is the difference between $x$ and $y$?"

To give an example (and my current use case): I want to compare the usage of words between two texts of similar size. Obviously, "and" will be used a lot by both texts, and one may use it hundreds of times more than the other, but it is overall insignificant. Similarly, one text may use one rare word once while the other doesn't, but this too is insignificant. However, if one text uses a certain word far more often than the other text, this is statistically significant, just like if one text uses a rare word multiple times.

Comment: You probably want something like a [relative difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference) (essentially, the difference, scaled by some function of the two inputs).

Comment: You are correct, that is the article I looked at while making this post, should have probably cited it. Functions 2 and 3 are two of the options from the several common choices listed on that article.

Comment: I don't think there's all that many great answers, since based on 2 and 4 you're not getting scale invariance. But given 1 and 3 you don't seem to want additive invariance. So whatever you get is going to be pretty arbitrary.

Comment: I agree that this function will be intrinsically arbitrary, and there might not be an ideal solution. However, there likely could be constant(s) in $f$ that could be tweaked to get the value returned to accurately answer the question "how big is the difference between the two values?".

Comment: @JasonCarr see my edit for option #4 as well as my expansion on my use case.

Comment: I don't have enough statistical expertise to answer your question, but thanks for the clarification of use case. This seems like a case of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your solution should likely be able to use standard statistical difference techniques.

Comment: Thinking about your last paragraph. It seems to me you have two separate issues, one for common words, one for rare words. Maybe you should quantify the two separately, and sound an alarm if either is high. // Maybe ratio of highest to lowest usage for common words, and high usage for rare words.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem slightly complicated, though it seems to give the sort of function you are looking for.

Taking a Bayesian approach, suppose as a prior that the proportion of occurrences of the first type among first and second types is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, i.e. has a $\text{Beta}(1,1)$ distribution

With your observations, your posterior distribution for that proportion would be $\text{Beta}(x+1,y+1)$ distributed, and your posterior probability that the first type is less common that the second would be $q=\int_0^{1/2}  \frac{p^{x}(1-p)^y}{\text{B}(x+1,y+1)}\,dp$

That will give a probability estimate $q$ in $(0,1)$.  Taking the log-odds (logit) would give $\log\left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$ which may meet your needs as a function

For example in R, you could construct this function

```
reldist <- function(m,n){pbeta(0.5,m+1,n+1,lower.tail=TRUE, log.p=TRUE) - 
                         pbeta(0.5,m+1,n+1,lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)}
```

which for example would give

```
> reldist(1,2)
[1] 0.7884574


x,y         reldist
---------   ---------- 
1,2         0.7884574
1000,1100   4.215137
100,300     55.41071
0,100       70.00787
100,100     0
2,1         -0.7884574
1100,1000   -4.215137
etc.
```

You can draw *significance* at any point you wish.  An arbitrary two-tailed probability of $5\%$ (so one-tailed of $2.5\%$) would correspond to log-odds critical points of about $\pm\log\left(\frac{0.025}{0.975}\right) \approx \pm 3.66$ so seeing $1000,1100$ might be seen as just significant on this basis; by contrast an arbitrary two-tailed probability of $0.1\%$ would correspond to log-odds critical points of about $\pm 7.6$